# R: Group by 2 columns but only when 2nd column doesn't match

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm new to R (and dplyr) and I'm currently working with some seasonal football data and need some help. Currently if a player transfers to another club in the same league then the row of data and all metrics is simply duplicated but with a new team_id. However if the player transfers to another league then the metrics are split.

For consistency's sake I need to resolve this which means that I have to:

> Group by player_id where comp_id does not match

(football regulations dictate that you can only play for a max. of 2 clubs in a season so this negates further complications and so this simple rule resolves everything)

so in other words if there are duplicates sum all rows but only if the comp_id differs

I was trying to do this in dplyr and was hoping that there would be some way of writing this such as:

```
football_data %>%
group_by(player_id, !comp_id)
```

but this doesn't work and quite rightly so.

My other option is to create an additional column based on a composite key (player_id, comp_id) and group_by player_id only where count of composite key = 1, but even then I'm struggling to write this with dplyr.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Edit:

There's close to a hundred metrics so I'll simplify as per below:

```
player_id   player_name   comp,   team,  metric1, metric2, metric3 .....
1            Lacazette     Bund   Dort     20       30       20
1            Lacazette     EPL    Ars      10       15       15
2            Arnautovic    EPL    Stoke    30       40       30     
2            Arnautovic    EPL    W. Ham   30       40       30
```

so in this example the data metrics are split when a player moves leagues (Lacazette) but not if the transfer is in the same league (Arnautovic).

So for consistency I need to sum the metrics for the first player but not  for the second player

resulting in an output:

```
player_id   player_name   comp,   team,  metric1, metric2, metric3 .....
1            Lacazette     Bund   Dort     30       45       35
1            Lacazette     EPL    Ars      30       45       35
2            Arnautovic    EPL    Stoke    30       40       30     
2            Arnautovic    EPL    W. Ham   30       40       30
```

Comment: you should provide the input data and expected output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you want to

1. get the player-level `sum` of the `metric` variables, grouped by `comp`
2. `join` them back into the full dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> -- Attaching packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
#> v ggplot2 2.2.1     v purrr   0.2.4
#> v tibble  1.4.1     v dplyr   0.7.4
#> v tidyr   0.7.2     v stringr 1.2.0
#> v readr   1.1.1     v forcats 0.2.0
#> -- Conflicts -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
#> x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

df <- data.frame(player_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
                 player_name = c("Lacazette", "Lacazette", "Arnuatovic", "Arnuatovic"), 
                 comp = c("Bund", "EPL", "EPL", "EPL"), 
                 team = c("Dort", "Ars", "Stoke", "W. Ham"), 
                 metric1 = c(20, 10, 30, 30), 
                 metric2 = c(30, 15, 40, 40), 
                 metric3 = c(20, 15, 30, 30))

df %>% 
  distinct(player_id, player_name, comp, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  group_by(player_id) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(metric1:metric3), funs(sum)) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% select(player_id:team), ., by = "player_id")


#>   player_id player_name comp   team metric1 metric2 metric3
#> 1         1   Lacazette Bund   Dort      30      45      35
#> 2         1   Lacazette  EPL    Ars      30      45      35
#> 3         2  Arnuatovic  EPL  Stoke      30      40      30
#> 4         2  Arnuatovic  EPL W. Ham      30      40      30
```